# wordpress is_page() problem

Tags: conditional-content

I want to load a .js file only on a specific page in Wordpress 3.1.2
So I use in functions.php

```
function my_init_method() {
if (is_page('myinfopage')){
   echo "yeeessssssss";
   //wp_register_script('RGraph',get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/RGraph/RGraph.common.core.js' );
   }
}
add_action('init', 'my_init_method');
```

The page is 100% 'myinfopage'. I tried it also with the pageID 24
if (is_page(24)){....

But nothing happens. It's not included and noe 'yeeesssss' is displayed.
Any idea?

Cheers, Joerg

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to drop the conditional during init. You are just registering the script here, not enqueueing it. Once registered, you should be able to call the script later in the action sequence. Please try something like this:

```
function myplugin_css() {
    if ( is_page( 'myinfopage' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'RGraph' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'myplugin_css' );
```

Comment: To add to Michael's answer: the 'init' hook is too soon to use conditionals such as `is_page()`. You need to use such conditionals late enough in the pageload for WordPress to have defined them. Since `wp_print_scripts` fires during `wp_head`, hooking into it is sufficiently late enough for `is_page()` to have been defined.

Answer (score 0):

add_action just hooks a function call to an event. In order to originally call the action you should use do_action..

Refer http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action